# Can't Install Linux Mint

Tags: installation, operating-systems, linux-mint

As the title says, I am having trouble installing the Linux Mint 13 Operating System in my computer and I am looking for advise on how to solve the problem. I hope you can help me.

I downloaded Linux Mint 13 with the MATE Desktop from [Linux Mint's Main Page](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php), and burnt it on a DVD, then started installing it.

After going through the configuring process and creating the Superuser account, the slideshow introducing Mint appeared, and 30 seconds or so after that, the installing window vanished, without giving notice about the installation progress. From then on when on the desktop, the pointer would always have the "waiting Icon".

After waiting for a while without seeing any changes, I restarted my PC and tried booting normally, to see if the installation had been completed without me knowing. But it wasn't complete. And Windows wasn't starting either.

So I did the whole thing again. This time instead of giving the choice of installing alongside Windows, the installing program gave me the choice of installing alongside Linux, so the installation was partially, yet not fully complete. The installing window vanished again after the first slide of the slideshow appeared.

I kept tried several times, re-burning the DVD once or twice, but to no avail. I wondered if this was happening because the ISO file had not been correctly downloaded, so I did it again (this time changing to the Cinnamon desktop since I didn't like MATE). And it happened exactly the same thing.

I noticed that the current state of the installation when the window closed was irrelevant; the window would always close after showing the first slide of the slideshow, so I guess the problem must have something to do with this, yet I have no idea what it could be.

I hope that someone can help me, I need to have Linux installed in this computer as soon as possible.

Comment: How much RAM is available in your system? Problem might be caused by low memory forcing the kernel to exit processes. If you just need to get some Linux system running, I recommend running a Linux live system like Knoppix. Keep in mind that this will require more RAM than installing a system to hard disk. So depending on your hardware specs this might not work for you also.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. At this moment I have 1.5GB available RAM. According to the requirements listed for this OS that's more than enough... isn't it?

Comment: 1.5 GiB should be enough for both Mint or a live system. Because this was the only reason (I can think of) that would directly relate to closing programs that run perfectly elsewhere, you might want to check the install disc's integrity and your RAM by using the appropriate items in the boot menu as a part of general troubleshooting.

Comment: With all the fixes on the Internet, I would've thought that I would'be been able to find a fix before making it up myself. These are, in fact, my posts: http://superuser.com/questions/1101648/grub2-failed-to-install-into-target This may not be the exact problem you found, but it's something different to look at. Let me know if it works.